# How to solve 'No module named pymysql'

Tags: python, pymysql

I use computer that is Window 10 and my Python version is 3.6.

I installed pymysql and MySQLdb as in the picture below.

[image]

But When I tried to run python, I got this error : No module named 'pymysql'
also, MySQLdb...

How can I solved it?

Comment: Post full error message with traceback please. Make sure that you are using the correct version by comparing the outputs of `pip --version` and `python --version`

Comment: What command did you use to install PyMySQL? Using `python3 -m pip install PyMySQL` and then `import pymysql` works for me.

Comment: I use command python -m pip install PyMySQL.. then I import pymysql. but i got error message that no module named 'pymysql'

Comment: I just got error message that no module named 'pymysql'. and my python version is 3.6.5 and pip version is 10.0.1.

Comment: Try using pip3 install pymysql, this worked for me

Comment: I tried to uninstall pymysql and install pymysql using pip3.. but the error message is still....

Comment: @SuYeonChoi I just tried to `pipenv install pymysql` and `pipenv install PyMySQL` in different environments. They are identical.

Comment: @SuYeonChoi it looks like you installed `pymysql` but you running another interpreter. Try `pip show pymysql` - do you see: `PyMySQL    0.8.1 ` ?. And I recommend to start using [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) instead of just `pip` as earlier than better.

Comment: I used pipenv.. but I got still the error..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `pip3 install PyMySQL` and `import pymysql`

Comment: And `venv` or `pipenv` for additional garantee